# qstat shell script issue

Tags: bash, shell, terminal, qsub

I am writing a shell script that starts some qsub jobs and check the status of the jobs. I want to store job status in a variable. For example, I have following lines in the script:

```
job=1808704.master.cm.cluster
job_stat=$(qstat $job)
```

Currently after running the job_stat command, my script shows job status on the console. However, I don't want to show the status on the console. I want to store it in  job_stat variable and want to fetch status result by using  $job_stat command. How to do that?

Comment: If the job status appears on the terminal and not in `$job_stat`, then `qstat` doesn't report its status on standard output. As such, it is aberrant; standard output goes to standard output so that things like [command substitution](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Command-Substitution) work correctly.  However, code is broken on occasion. You need to establish where `qstat` does write.  It may write to standard error, in which case `job_stat=$(qstat $job 2>&1)` would capture the output (and any error message). But it might write to `/dev/tty` or (worse) `/dev/console`.

Comment: I have tried it but still have the same problem.

Comment: I don't seem to have access to the commands, even though the manual pages are there (which is curious).  The manual pages quote from POSIX, and say that the output should be written to standard output unless it is an error message, in which case it should go to standard error.  Are you really asking about how the `qsub` command reports the job ID?  Is there no-one where you work who uses the system?